# How to redirect to another component after checking conditions in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am new to Angular 8 and i am making a login component and after entering username password i want to redirect to another component using route thats my code i have done this much :

my login component.ts:

```
       import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
       import{FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators} from '@angular/forms'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm:FormGroup
  submitted=false;
  _baseURL : string;
  formvalid: boolean;
   user:string;
   pwd:string;
  constructor(private formbuilder:FormBuilder){}


  ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm = this.formbuilder.group({
    username:['',Validators.required],
    password:['',[Validators.required,Validators.pattern("^(?=.*?[a-z])(.{13,}|(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,12})$")]]
    });
    this._baseURL="";
    this.formvalid=false;
  }

  Submitme(){
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.myForm.invalid) {
      this.formvalid=false;
        return;
    }
    if (this.myForm.valid) {
      this.formvalid=true;
    this._baseURL= 'Welcome'+" "+ this.myForm.controls.username.value;
  }
  this.user=this.myForm.controls.username.value;
  this.pwd=this.myForm.controls.password.value;
}
rest(){
  this.myForm.reset();
  this.submitted = false;
}
}
```

my login component html is:

```
        <h1 class="text-center" [hidden]="formvalid">Login</h1>
          <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="Submitme()" class="text-center">
           <div class="container bg-dark" [hidden]="formvalid" style="border: 1px solid black;">
         <div class="row mt-3">
           <div class="col-lg-5">
         <label for="name" class="text-white">Username :</label>
         </div>
         <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="col-lg-4 form-control"
           [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted &amp;&amp; myForm.controls.username.errors }">
          <div *ngIf="submitted &amp;&amp; myForm.controls.username.errors" class="text-danger">
            <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.username.errors.required">First Name is required</div>
        </div>
       </div>
     <div class="row mt-2">
           <div class="col-lg-5">
       <label for="pwd" class="text-white">Password :</label>
         </div>
      <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="col-lg-4 form-control"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted &amp;&amp; myForm.controls.password.errors }">
       <div *ngIf="submitted &amp;&amp; myForm.controls.password.errors" class="text-danger">
     <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.password.errors.required">password is required</div>
      <div *ngIf="myForm.controls.password.errors.pattern">Pwd must contain atleast one upper and 
    lower case character one special character one digit and 8 characters in length  </div>
   </div>
    </div>
     <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-3" type="submit" 
   [routerLink]="'/afterlog'">Submit</button>&nbsp;
     <input type="button" (click)="rest()" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary mt-2 mb-3">
 </div>
      </form>
```

After login i want to redirect to another component with welcome message using routing in angular 8:
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: In wide strokes, inject `Router` into your component, and redirect by `this.router.navigate` or `this.router.navigateByUrl`, depending on your needs.

Comment: is there any **answer** helpful for you.

Comment: @SaisivaA:Yes using queryParam i found it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you you want to navigate to the new component and sending the new data to show the welcome message there, you can navigate with sending queryParams, send your **username** as a **queryParam** to welcome component, You can store the loggedin user in **localstorage** too if you want and avoid sending it as query parameter

```
this.router.navigate(['/welcome'], { queryParams: { username: this.myForm.controls.username.value} });
```

and you can construct the message in your welcome.component.ts

```
username: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.username= this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('username');
}
```

and in your welcome.component.html

```
<div>Welcome {{username}}!</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Define routes in your module file (eg. app.module):

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  ...
})
```

And in your login component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private _router: Router) { }

Submitme() {
  ...
  this._router.navigateByUrl('/welcome');  // open welcome component
}
```

For more details refer [here](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Comment: You made a small mistake. You name the variable _router and then use this.router below. It should be this._router.navigateByUrl('/welcome')

Comment: You're welcome, I wanted to edit it for you, but needed to change a minimum of 6 characters :p

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you want to navigate to a new page after they submit the form?

First you need to inject the Router class in your constructor. 
Add this in your constructor: 
`private router: Router`

And add this import: `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Now you can make use of the Router class in your TS file.

to navigate to an other page you use this syntax: `this.router.navigate(['/']);`
The example above would to to the home page.

You can also navigate relative to some path like this:
First add this to your constructor: `private route: ActivatedRoute`
And import ActivatedRoute
Then you can navigate relative to the current route like this: `this.router.navigate(['../../'], { relativeTo: this.route });`

this.route is the ActivatedRoute reference

For more on routing and navigation check: https://angular.io/guide/router